# Rouche's Theorem proof modified

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is a modified proof of Rouche's Theorem, i only changed the last part where one needs to show the integral will be $0$. However, the book Bak and Newman uses winding numbers, in which i have yet to read. Will anyone verify if my logic is correct if i just use merely cauchy goursat to do?

Note first that if $f(z) = h(z) \cdot k(z)$, then $$\dfrac{f^{'}(z)}{f(z)} = \dfrac{h^{'}(z)}{h(z)}+ \dfrac{k^{'}(z)}{k(z)}$$

So that we have $$\int_{C}\dfrac{f^{'}(z)}{f(z)}dz = \int_{C}\dfrac{h^{'}(z)}{h(z)}dz  + \int_{C}\dfrac{k^{'}(z)}{k(z)}dz$$

Thus if we write $$f(z) + g(z) = f(z) \cdot \left(1+ \frac{g(z)}{f(z)}\right)$$

It follows from the Argument Principle that the number of zeros of $f+g$ in $C$ is evaluated as

$\begin{aligned}
Z(f+g) & = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\dfrac{(f+g)^{'}}{f+g}dz\\
  & = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C} \dfrac{f^{'}(1+\frac{g}{f})+f(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{f(1+\frac{g}{f})}dz\\
  &= \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C} \dfrac{f^{'}}{f}dz + \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C}\dfrac{(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{1+\frac{g}{f}}dz\\
  &= Z(f)  + \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C}\dfrac{(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{1+\frac{g}{f}}dz\\
\end{aligned}$

Since we are dealing with a compact set in $\mathbb{C}$, we have $|g|$ and $|f|$ to be both bounded in the circle $C$. Consequently, $\left|\dfrac{g}{f}\right|$ is bounded in $C$. Assume that $f$ has zeros $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$, and since $\left|\dfrac{g}{f}\right|$ is bounded in each deleted neighborhood of an isolated singularity, the singularity is removable. Consequently, $\dfrac{g}{f}$ is analytic in and on $C$. It follows that $1+\dfrac{g}{f}$ is analytic in and on $C$.

Next we look at if there are any singularities in $C$ for the function $\dfrac{(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{1+\frac{g}{f}}$. The singularities of this will occur iff $$1+\dfrac{g}{f} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{g}{f} = -1 \Leftrightarrow f = -g \Leftrightarrow |f| = |-g| = |g|$$

Thus this leads to a contradiction as our hypothesis and extreme value theorem says $|g| < |f|\leq M$ on the boundary, by the maximum modulus, the maximum of $|g|$ occurs on the boundary and hence we are sure that inside the circle $C$, $|g| < |f| \leq M$ as well. Hence there are no zeros or singularities inside the $C$ as $1+\dfrac{g}{f}$ is non vanishing.

Hence we have $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C}\dfrac{(1+\frac{g}{f})^{'}}{1+\frac{g}{f}}dz = 0$ by Cauchy Goursat.

Consequently, $Z(f+g) = Z(f)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:

> The singularities of this will occur iff
> $$1 + \dfrac{g}{f} = 0 = \cdots$$

is false. If, for example, $f(z_0) = 0$, $g(z_0)\ne 0$, the integrand will have a singularity at $z_0 = 0$.

Also:

> ... since $∣g/f|$ is bounded in each deleted neighborhood of an isolated singularity...

is obviously false.

Comment: Yes i mentioned it in the previous paragraph where i took into consideration of the poles of $g/f$ and claim they are removable. Maybe the following paragraphs are redundant.

Comment: @ilovewt, take $f(z) = z$, $g(z) = 1$. The integrand  will have a pole at $z = 0$.

Comment: Would you be able to modify my proof to make it work? I thought that the function $g/f$ is bounded in the contour and hence the singularities will be all removable..

Comment: @ilovewt, by continuity $g/f$ will be bounded in the contour except if you have some $1/0$ *in the contour*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would i be able to work around the issue of $something/0$ ? Since it can be proven with winding numbers that the integral is $0$, then i think one can use Cauchy Theorem on it as well.

Comment: @ilovewt, in the points with $g/f = (\ne 0)/0$ the *integrand* has a simple pole for any multiplicity of the zero of $f$. Another possible case: $g/f = 0/0$ but pole.

Comment: @ilovewt, I can't continue now.  Check your proof against the case $f(z) = a z^m$, $g(z) = b z^n$.